# move a div above and to the right of another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

My blog has a cover photo (A) and posts (B) below it. When the page becomes wider than tall, I want the posts to appear on the left side of the cover photo. Is there a way to take div B and position it inline with A and to the left of it while still maintaining their widths?

tall view

```
--------------------
|        A         |
--------------------
--------
|  B   |
--------
```

wide view

```
-------- --------------------
|  B   | |        A         |
-------- --------------------
```

here is a link to the [index.html](https://github.com/andykais/andykais-blog/blob/gh-pages/index.html) and the [css](https://github.com/andykais/andykais-blog/blob/gh-pages/_includes/css/main.css). I am using jekyll so some things are included elsewhere but the important stuff is what is in those two files

Comment: use CSS : `float:left;` to both the divs

Comment: Please post your code. Also 'B' can be seen left in your example, and right in description, be specific what you want.

Comment: changed it to left, thanks for that catch

Comment: _I want the posts to appear on the **right** side of the cover photo._

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query to change the elements settings. To put them side by size, and to change the order, you can use a flexbox on their container, and give each item his order number ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb1sxwn4/1/)):

HTML layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="coverImage"></div>
    <div class="posts"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.coverImage {
    max-width: 400px; /** set max width so div won't be 100% **/
}

.posts {
    max-width: 400px; /** set max width so div won't be 100% **/
}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
    }

    .coverImage, .posts {
        flex: 1;
    }

    .coverImage {
        order: 2;
    }

    .posts {
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the way his html is the "B" comes after the "A", so `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` will make the cover photos come before the posts, right?

Comment: Well - the description say: "I want the posts to appear on the right side of the cover photo"

Comment: apologies, I do want B to the left of A

Comment: to change order, `display: flex` is the best option.

Comment: this does not work, it results in the two divs staclomg on top of each other at the same width. the `.coverImage` uses background image, though that should not affect anything

Comment: Resize the width of the bottom left panel by dragging the vertical border to the left. The demo works on new browsers, if you are using an old version of ie, some changes should be made.